# When is baking rewards counted to the staking balance?

Tags: baking

I have two related questions about my "staking rewards" or the number of rolls towards baking. Does my deposits made from baking or endorsing count towards the staking balance? Also, are locked rewards counted toward my staking balance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Frozen deposits are part of the staking balance (otherwise, your staking balance would decrease during baking);
- Frozen rewards are not part of the staking balance. They are taken into account only when they are unfrozen.

If you look at:
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/src/delegate_storage.ml#L445

You will see that only the rewards are added to the roll storage at the end of the cycle, neither the deposits (never removed) nor the fees (added immediately after the block).

Comment: Hi fabrice i could not locate in the documentation where they mention what you say regarding security deposit still counting towards the staking balance. Could you please add a pointer to a source ? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my post with a link to the sources.

Comment: thanks! Would be probably be worth updating http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html to precise this over there too. Maybe in the roll section (to say they are unimpacted by security deposit) and in the security deposit section (to say they dont impact the number of rolls owned)

Answer (score 1):

Yes all your deposits participate in the approval of new units[image]

Comment: FWIW, this is a snapshot of TzScan "Balance" tab of an account.